# If $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, why is $\epsilon$ zero here?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

If Epsilon is zero as in the last line of the answer provided, then wouldn't the limit definition fail? So Epislon has to be larger than zero? Please see the last line of the proof, taken from MathOnline[image]

Comment: The definition of limit requires $\epsilon > 0$. Otherwise only constant functions can satisfy the conditions. See the first sentence of your excerpt.

Comment: @player3236 please see the last line of the proof, it says Epsilon=0 resulting in L-M=0

Comment: "But $\epsilon > 0$ is arbitrary, so this implies that $|L-M| = 0$, that is $L=M$". Where exactly is the claim that $\epsilon = 0$?

Comment: beause >0 is arbitrary so we can set  to be zero, please help me out

Comment: $0 \not > 0$. So we cannot set $\epsilon = 0$.

Comment: ok thank you, -

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We never put $\epsilon=0$, but we let $\epsilon$ **tend** to zero.

If some quantity $Q$ satisfies $|Q|<\epsilon$ for **every** $\epsilon$, then by letting $\epsilon\to 0$ we conclude that $Q=0$. This is because the inequality holds for $\epsilon=\frac{1}{n}$ for every $n$ (for example), and so $|Q|<\frac{1}{n}$ for every natural number $n$. Now let $n\to\infty$. Another way to see it: if it weren't true that $Q=0$, then $|Q|>0$, and so by taking $\epsilon=\frac{|Q|}{2}$ we would violate our assumption that $|Q|<\epsilon$ for **every** $\epsilon>0$.

Answer (score 5):

The proof is divided in four parts. In the first one says "let $\varepsilon>0$ be given" and the third part finishes with $|L-M| < \varepsilon$. Hence, the proof shows the following:

> **Proposition.** For every $\varepsilon>0$, $|L-M| < \varepsilon$.

Now, how can exactly conclude that $|L-M| = 0$? Well, what happens if $|L-M| \neq 0$? Note that if $|L-M| \neq 0$ then $|L-M| > 0$, and then, taking $\varepsilon = |L-M|$ in the proposition we end up with $|L-M| < |L-M|$, a contradiction. Hence $|L-M| = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Epsilon is not zero but arbitrary. In the definition of the Limit it was shown that $f$ converges to $L$ if we can get $f(x)$ arbitrarily close by restricting $|x-c|< \delta$.

In the next step, we show das $L$ and $M$ must be arbitrarily close to each other because they are both arbitrarily close to $f$ for a sufficiently small $\delta$.